# Storing value of pointer to specialized template function

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, undefined-behavior, rtti

I would like to use some comparable representation of type, which is not direct like std::is_same<> and does not use RTTI. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro gives same string for 2 different classes with same name defined in different .cpp files in anonymous namespaces and comparing strings is slow.

Let's consider such a piece of code:

```
template<typename T>
void func() {}

int main() {
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&func<int>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&func<float>) << std::endl;
}
```

1. Is storing numeric value of pointer to specialized template function well defined behaviour? It will not be called anywhere.
2. Will it have same value in different .cpp files for same specialization?
3. Will it have same value between dynamic linked libraries - probably not?

Comment: First of all, what is the *real* problem you try to solve? *Why* do you want to do something like this? Related reading about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Secondly, if you want an integer-type to store a pointer use `uintptr_t` instead. And remember that pointers to functions are equal to normal pointers on *most* systems, but there are systems and platforms where they are *not* the same.

Comment: I'm trying to make `std::any` counterpart which would be usable without RTTI and exceptions. `std::any` actually works without RTTI, but the only way to check if it contains concrete type(with RTTI disabled) is using `std::any_cast<T>` which will terminate application if type does not match and exceptions are disabled. I need mechanism to check if it is safe to `reinterpret_cast` containing data to concrete type.